# MVVMCross changing selected tab bar item from within nested view controller

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

We're using MVVMCross within our application and I've come up against something that I'm not sure I've solved in the best way possible.

One of our ViewModels contains 3 other view models - a dashboard and 2 lists. In iOS this is presented using a MvxTabBarViewController which works great. Android and WP present this view in a similar manner. An example of the object model is below:

```
public class ProjectViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public DashboardViewModel Dashboard {get;set;}
    public FirstListViewModel FirstList {get;set;}
    public SecondListViewModel SecondList {get;set;}
}
```

We're now in the situation where if a certain action happens within the DashboardViewModel we would like to instruct the navigation to change the tab in iOS and the same thing to happen on the other platforms.

The only way I've been able to get the tab to change on iOS is to use this.SelectedIndex = 1; from within the iOS ProjectView.

At the moment also the only way I've managed to trigger this change is to fire an event from the DashboardViewModel and then the ProjectViewModel subscribes to this and fires another event which is subscribed to by the ProjectView to instruct it to change the tab in whatever device specific way it needs to. I can't help but think there is a better way to do this.

I've tried taking a look at a custom ViewPresenter for iOS and calling ShowViewModel FirstListViewModel from within the DashboardViewModel but the presenter doesn't appear to be getting used so we just transition normally. My idea was I could get in the middle, cancel the navigation request and then flip the active tab on the ProjectView.

Any suggestions would be appreciated on how we could do this in a better cross platform way using MVVMCross to handle the change if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in any of several ways:

- using a custom presenter with overridden `Show` as you suggest
- using a custom presenter with overridden ChangePresentation - and using a custom hint
- using a custom binding or a binding to a property within the ProjectView to drive the transition
- using a custom `IMvxInteraction` property
- using a custom event from VM to View
- using a messenger to send a message from the ViewModels to the Views.

Ultimately lots of these could work and which of these I might choose would depend on which one worked and which one the team are happy with - shipping the working app is always the ultimate goal.

---

Given where I am with MvvmCross experience, I'd probably opt today for trying the approach of trying a custom `IMvxInteraction` property. But this might not be for everyone... it certainly might be **overkill** for this sample...

However, to do this, I would try:

- add a `public enum Display { Dash, First, Second }` to the Core project
- add a `ProjectViewModel` property:

  ```
  private MvxInteraction<Display> _display = new MvxInteraction< Display >();
  public IMvxInteraction<Display> DisplayChange { get { return _display; } }
  ```
- whenever this ViewModel wants to fire the change it can fire it using e.g. `_display.Raise(Display.First)`
- the `ProjectView` could then bind `Display` to its own property which might be implemented like:

  ```
  private IDisposable _subscription;
  private IMvxInteraction<Display> _displayInteraction;
  public IMvxInteraction<Display> ChangeDisplay
  {
      get { return _displayInteraction; }
      set
      {
          if (_subscription != null)
          {
              _subscription.Dispose();
              _subscription = null;
          }
          _displayInteraction = value;
          if (_displayInteraction != null)
          {
              _subscription = _displayInteraction.WeakSubscribe(DoDisplayChange);
          }
      }
  }

  private void DoDisplayChange(Display which)
  {
     // change the tab display here
  }
  ```
- the binding would be added in ViewDidLoad like:

  ```
  set.Bind(this).For(v => v.ChangeDisplay).To(vm => vm.DisplayChange);
  ```

Comment: Thanks very much Stuart for such a comprehensive reply and for MVVMCross. Great framework!